# Morphism between quotient polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, quotient-spaces

Le $\Bbb{K}$ be a field.
I want to show wether $\frac{\Bbb{K}[X]}{\langle X^2 \rangle}$ and $\frac{\Bbb{K}[X]}{\langle X^2  + 1\rangle}$ are isomorphic.

First thing to note is that there is an nilpotent element $[X]$ in the first quotient. But in the second one I think it will depend on the roots of $X^2+1$ because for example in $\Bbb{F}_2$, $x^2+1=(X-1)^2$ so $[X-1]$ is nilpotent. So in the case where it can't be factorized there is no nilpotent element (how to prove that ?). Otherwise I don't see any morphism we can exhibit.

Any hint ?

Comment: It depends on $K$. For example, for the complex numbers both polynomials are reducible. For real numbers, the rings are of course not isomorphic. The second quotient ring then is a field, the first one not. For $2=0$ see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108724/are-there-fields-f-such-that-the-rings-fx-x2-and-fx-x2-1-are-iso).

Comment: Hint: if $K[X]/(X^2+1)$ has a nilpotent element, it means that $X^2+1$ has a repeated irreducible factor in its decomposition, in particular that $X^2+1$ isn’t coprime to its derivative. Can you work out in which $K$ this happens?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ok I didn't found that this question was already answered. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will change your $\Bbb K$ to $K$, for simplicity. All isomorphism below are isomorphisms of rings (or $K$-algebras, actually).

The structure of $K[X]/(X^2 + 1)$ depends on the number of different roots of the polynomial $X^2 + 1$ in $K$. There can be three situations:

- There are two different roots $r_1, r_2$. We then have $$K[X]/(X^2 + 1) \simeq K[X]/(X - r_1) \times K[X]/(X - r_2)$$ by chinese remainder theorem, and each factor $K[X]/(X - r_i)$ is canonically isomorphic to $K$. Hence $K[X]/(X^2 + 1) \simeq K^2$ in this case.
- There is one double root $r$. It is easy to see that this happens iff the characteristic of $K$ is equal to $2$, and in that case we have $X^2 + 1 = (X + 1)^2$, hence $$K[X]/(X^2 + 1) \simeq K[X]/(X + 1)^2 \simeq K[X]/X^2$$ via evident isomorphisms.
- There is no root, i.e. $-1$ is not a square in $K$. In this case, $K[X]/(X^2 + 1)$ is a field, which is the quadratic extension $K[\sqrt{-1}]$ of $K$.

---

We see that in the second case, we do have $K[X]/(X^2 + 1) \simeq K[X]/X^2$.

In the remaining two cases, $K[X]/(X^2 + 1)$ is a product of fields, hence does not have any nilpotent element, while $X$ is a nilpotent element in $K[X]/X^2$. Thus they are not isomorphic in these two cases.

To summerize, we have $K[X]/(X^2 + 1) \simeq K[X]/X^2$ iff the characteristic of $K$ is equal to $2$.