# Show $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-cx) \ncong \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, polynomial-rings

> For integers $c \ge 2$, prove $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2 - cx) \ncong \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. (Hint: for a ring $A$, consider $A/pA$ for a suitable prime $p$.)

I'm not entirely sure what the hint means, and I don't really have an idea for an approach.  For context, this is part (c) of a question; part (a) was to show that $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2) \ncong \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$, and part (b) was to show $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2 - x) \cong \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$.  I was able to do both, though my approaches for those questions don't seem to apply for this one.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Choose $p$ so $\,x^2-cx\pmod p\,$ reduces to the appropriate prior problem (except over $\,\Bbb Z/p).\ \ \ $

Comment: How did you approached in the case of $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2-x)$ and why can't it be applied here? Please show in more detail why you believe this happens to fail.

Comment: @mrtaurho I took a homomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb Z[x] \to \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ by $\varphi(f) = (f(0), f(1))$ and applied the first isomorphism theorem. It doesn’t work here since the analogous homomorphism isn’t surjective.

Comment: The ring $R[x]/x^2$ is known as the algebra of **dual numbers** over $R$. It proves useful for studying derivatives and tangent / jet spaces, e.g. see [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17151/242)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since I'm the one who wrote this past prelim problem that you're asking about (I recognized it immediately since you used the notation $c$ in the coefficient of $x$ from the original prelim problem), perhaps I'm "most" suited to answering it. :)

A general thing to keep in mind is that you can show two rings are not isomorphic by showing they don't share some ring-theoretic property preserved by isomorphisms: one has a finite unit group and the other doesn't, one is a field and the other isn't, one is a PID and the other has a nonprincipal ideal, and so on. How did you handle (a)?

For (c), the point of the hint is to look at the ring structure on both sides after you reduce them mod $p$ for a prime $p$. On the right side you get $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z) \times (\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)$, a product of two fields. As Bill Dubuque indirectly hinted at in his comment, there is a big difference on the left side (that is, for $\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2-cx)$) if you reduce it mod $p$ for a prime $p$ where $p \mid c$ or where $p \nmid c$. For $c \geq 2$ there is going to be a prime of the first kind and that's what makes $c \geq 2$ different from $c = 1$.

By the way, the source of this prelim problem is that in a paper I read before the prelim was being prepared, the author used the "fact" that $\mathbf Z[x]/(f(x)g(x)) \cong \mathbf Z[x]/(f(x)) \times \mathbf Z[x]/(g(x))$ for two relatively prime polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$, and that is generally incorrect. If the coefficient ring were a field, like $\mathbf Q$, then the isomorphism would be valid. But $\mathbf Z$ is not a field and the proof of the Chinese remainder theorem for polynomials over a field does not go through for polynomials over $\mathbf Z$ all the time. This prelim problem has the simplest example I could think of (simplest nonconstant $f(x)$ and $g(x)$) where there is no ring isomorphism: not just that the "obvious" homomorphism $h(x) \bmod x^2-cx \mapsto (h(0),h(c))$ from $\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2-cx)$ to $\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z$ is not a ring isomorphism, but that there is no ring isomorphism at all.

Comment: Not sure what is "indirect" about my hint. I was attempting to say only enough  to help the OP past the stumbling block - without spoiling the hint.  Interesting to learn of such a basic mistake in a research paper. Of course it occurs frequently in math forums such as here, sci.math, etc. I suppose that implies that there are some presentations out there on these topics that leave much to be desired.

Comment: I meant "indirect" only in the sense of you not being more explicit about the choice of $p$. I don't want to say in a public forum like this which research paper had that error of using CRT in $\mathbf Z[x]$. The author was able to fix the mistake by focusing more closely on the specific case of interest.

Comment: @BillDubuque if you're curious and can find my email address then you can write to me and I'll let you know which paper it was (offer for Bill only).

Comment: Wow, this is fortuitous.  Thank you for the help!  For part (a), I noted that in $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2)$, there are 6 units: $1 + (x^2), -1 + (x^2), 1 - x + (x^2), 1 + x + (x^2), -1 + x + (x^2), -1 - x + (x^2)$.  Whereas in $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$, there are four: $(1, 1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, -1)$.

Comment: That's incorrect: $1 + ax$ is a unit in $\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2)$ for *all* integers $a$ since in this ring $(1+ax)(1 - ax) = 1 - a^2x^2 = 1$.  Reconsider why you thought there are only $6$ units in $\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2)$. Counting units (correctly) is a way to distinguish $\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2)$ and $\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z$ as rings, but there are other methods, such as looking at *nilpotent* elements in each ring.

Comment: @KCd Can you look at my solution below? Yours/Bills argument is definitely easier, but mine does not use the hint.

Comment: @Mike I added an answer which elaborates on the concepts underlying the approach in your answer (induced comaximal factorizations).

Answer (score 7):

It is instructive to bring to the fore the conceptual key idea that is implicit in Mike's answer.
**Hint** $ $  by the Lemma $\,\Bbb Z[x]/(x(c\!-\!x))\cong\:\! \Bbb Z\!\times\! \Bbb Z\,$ $\Rightarrow\, \overbrace{x\,a(x)\!+\!(c\!-\!x)\,b(x) = 1}^{\large x,\ c-x\ \ \rm are\ \color{#0a0}{comaximal}^{\phantom{}}}\ \ \smash{\overset{x\,\to\, 0}\Longrightarrow}\ \  \bbox[4px,border:1px solid #0a0]{c\mid 1} $

**Idea** $ $ proper factorizations of $\,R/f\,$ $\rm\small\color{#f60}{induce}$ coprime $\small\rm\color{#0a0}{(i.e. comaximal)}$ proper
factorizations of $f\,$ by

**Lemma** $\,  $ If $\,\begin{align}f\in R\,\ \rm  a\ UFD,\\ {\rm rings}\ G,H\!\neq 0\end{align}\ $ then $\, \begin{align} R/f\,\ &\smash{\overset{\pi_{\phantom{|}}\!}\cong}\,\ G\!\times\! H\\ \color{#f60}{\bf\large  \Rightarrow} f\ \  &\!\!=\ g\ h\end{align} $ with $\ \begin{align} &\color{#0a0}{(g)\!+\!(h)=(1)^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!}\\ &\,(g),\, (h)\neq\:\! (1)\end{align}\,$ for some $\,g,h\in R^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\!$

**Proof** $\ $ Isomorphism $\,\pi\,$ maps the idempotent $\,\varepsilon =(1,0)\in G\!\times\! H\,$ to one  $\, \bar e =  e\!+\!(f)^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\!\,$  in $\,R/f\,$ by  $\pi$ maps $(1,0)^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\!=\!(1,0)^2$ to $\, \bar e = \bar e^2.\,$ $\,\bar e\,$ is $\,\small\rm\color{#c00}{nontrivial}$: $\,H\!\neq 0\,\Rightarrow\,\varepsilon \neq (0,0),(1,1)^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\!\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{\bar e\neq 0,1}$.
[Thus by](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1137785/242) $R^{\phantom{|^{|^{|^|}}}}\!\!\!\!$ a UFD, $\:f^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\!\mid (1\!-\!e)e\,\Rightarrow\, f=gh,\,\ g\mid 1\!-\!e,\,\ h\mid e$ $\,\Rightarrow\, (g)^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\!+\!(h)\supseteq(1\!-\!e)\!+\!(e)=(1),\:$ and the factorization is proper: $\, g\mid 1^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\! \Rightarrow f\mid h\mid e\,\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{\bar e=0}\,$ and $\,h\mid 1^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\Rightarrow f\mid g\mid 1\!-\!e\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{\bar e=1}$.

**Remark**  $\, $ Generally $\small\rm\color{#c00}{nontrivial}$ idempotents (i.e. elements satisfying $\,e^2 = e\,$ and $\,\color{#c00}{e\neq 0,1})\,$ are [intimately connected to coprime factorizations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614256/242) (of both elements and rings). In fact some integer factorization algorithms work by searching for nontrivial idempotents mod $\,n,\,$ which immediately yield a factorization of $\,n\,$ ([generally we can quickly factor $\,n\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4604/242) given any polynomial which has more roots mod $\,n\,$ than its degree, so any nontrivial idempotent or nontrivial square-root will split $\,n,\,$ since it yields a quadratic with $\,\color{c00}3\,$ roots).

Also closely related: the natural map $\, R\, \to R/I \times R/J\,$ is surjective $\!\iff\! I+J = (1),\,$ e.g. see Prop. $1.10$ in Atiyah and Macdonald's [Introduction to Commutative Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201407515). This is well known in elementary number theory as the case $\,(a,b)=(1,0)\,$ of the [CRT solvability criterion,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242) i.e. $\,x\equiv a\pmod{\!i},\, x\equiv b\pmod{\!j}\,$ is solvable $\!\iff$  $\,\gcd(i,j)\mid a\!-\!b,\,$ i.e. $\,a\!-\!b\in(i)+(j)$.

Comment: I find this answer very difficult to read.

Comment: @Eric If that's the reason for the downvote then why didn't you first explain what you found difficult so I could improve it. I have no idea what that is since you don't say. Is it just a matter of style or something more?

Comment: The formatting of everything before the Remark is hard to parse, especially the vertical stacking in the statement of the Lemma.  I like the use of color but otherwise I think it would be much easier to follow if you just wrote in ordinary sentences.

Comment: @Eric  My answers strive to show in a *single glance* the key ideas. Breaking things down into more verbose natural language often destroys the logical flow of the ideas that I am explicitly striving to highlight (e.g. the above stacking and notation is meant to strongly emphasize that the ring factorization implies the comaximal element factorization) This may require some small extra effort to parse, but that is effort well-spent if it helps readers to quickly see the key ideas (which might be *much* more difficult to infer if obfuscated in much more verbose or linear-constrained text).

Comment: Btw, if the above hint or sketched proof is too concise for anyone then please (always) feel welcome to ask for elaboration and I will happily oblige.

Comment: @BillDubuque don't worry about downvotes, I've just upvoted but really there's no need to worry about them. Especially you, you have 229k!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 - cx) \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. Let $\varphi$ denote an isomorphism between these rings. I will denote a coset with an overline to simplify notation. Then, $\varphi(\overline{x}(\overline{x-c}))=\varphi(\overline{x})\varphi(\overline{x-c}) = (0,0)$, and $\varphi(\overline{x})$ and $\varphi(\overline{x-c})$ are not $0$ since $\varphi$ is injective. Therefore, $\varphi(\overline{x}) = (m,0)$ and $\varphi(\overline{x - c}) = (0,n)$ or vice versa for some *nonzero* $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ (WLOG, assume the former).

From
\begin{align*}
(0,n) & = \varphi(\overline{x - c}) \\ 
& = \varphi(\overline{x} - \overline{c}) \\
& = \varphi(\overline{x}) - \varphi(\overline{c}) \\
& = (m,0) - (c,c) \\
& = (m-c,-c)
\end{align*}
we get $m = c$ and $n = -c$. Hence, $\varphi(\overline{x}) = (c,0)$ and $\varphi(\overline{x-c}) = (0,-c)$. Pick $\overline{f(x)} \in \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 -cx)$ such that $\varphi(\overline{f(x)}) = (1,0)$. Since every polynomial in the quotient can be represented by a polynomial of degree $0$ or $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and integers in $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-cx)$ 
are images of integers, by injectivity of $\varphi$ we can choose $f$ to have degree $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then, since $c\varphi(\overline{f(x)}) = \varphi(\overline{x})$ we have $c\overline{f(x)} = \overline{x}$ in the quotient. Hence in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, 
$$
cf(x) = x + g(x)(x^2 -cx)
$$
for some $g \in \mathbb Z[x]$. If $g(x)$ is nonzero then the left side has degree $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and the right side has degree larger than $1$. This means that $g(x) = 0$ and thus we have $x = cf(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ which is a contradiction since $x$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $c$ is a non-unit in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ because $c \geq 2$.

Comment: First you say $x + g(x)(x^2-cx)$ has degree larger than $1$ and then you say $g(x) = 0$, which makes its degree not larger than 1. Write the last reasoning in the last four lines more clearly.  And you never used $c \not= 1$ in an essential way earlier when you said there's an $f(x)$ where $\varphi(\overline{f(x)}) = (1,0)$. There has to be such an $f(x)$ simply because $(1,0)$ is in the image, whether or not $c = 1$.

Comment: @KCd I just edited my answer. For your second comment is the $c \neq 1$ needed to ensure that $\overline{f(x)} \neq \overline{x}$?

Comment: You should never start written sentences with symbols, as it makes them hard to read.  See where you have "$\ldots (1,0). c \not= 1\ldots$'': yuck.

Comment: You don't *need* to say anything about $c$ not being $1$ where you introduce $\overline{f(x)}$.  Who cares if $\overline{f(x)}$ is $\overline{x}$ or not? It's irrelevant. The only place $c \geq 2$ is essential is at the very end. From $x = cf(x)$ you get a contradiction from $c \geq 2$ by comparing leading coefficients on both sides.

Comment: Okay, I edited my last sentence.

Comment: You missed part of my point.  The *first* place you wrote $c \not= 1$, it's irrelevant. It is unnecessary to appeal to $c \not= 1$ when you first define $\overline{f(x)}$.

Comment: Ah Sorry, I misread your prior statements. You are correct, it is not necessary to invoke the $c \neq 1$ hypothesis until the end. I have fixed my answer to reflect this.