# Understanding surjectivity in Chinese Remainder Theorem Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem, ring-homomorphism

Im self-studying some ring theory and in Dummit and Foote Chapter 7.6 Theorem 17, pg 265-266 they have a proof for the case where $k = 2$ that I am struggling to understand--maybe I'm forgetting some identity or don't have the correct grasp on 'mod'-- but basically it says that if $A,B $ are ideals of $R$, the map $\phi : R \to R/A \times R/B$ defined by $\phi(r) = (r + A, r+ B)$ is a surjective homomorphism iff A and B are comaximal. I see that the function is a homomorphism but dont follow their reasoning as to why its surjective. I understand the notation $r+A \in R/A$ far more than the mod notation, if that helps.

Comment: This is false without some assumptions on the ideals, so you will need those assumptions to make the proof work.  (Comaximal or coprime most likely)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095229/242) is some motivation of the innate *linearity* exploited there, viz. $\,(a,b) = a(1,0) + b(0,1)\ \ $

Comment: @Randall you're right! I forgot to add that part when transcribing thank you

Comment: It would help if your explained more precisely exactly which parts of that reasoning that you don't follow.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\phi$ is surjective. Then for every $x,y$ there exists $ z$ such that $x+A=z+A, y+B=z+B$ so $ z-x\in A, z-y\in B$. Take $x=1,y=0$. So there exists $z$ such that $z-1\in A, z\in B$. Hence $A+B$ contains $1$, $A+B=R$, so $A,B$ are co-maximal.

Now suppose that $A,B$ are co-maximal, $a+b=1$ where $a\in A, b\in B$. Then take any $x,y\in R$. We need to find a $z\in R$ such that $z-x\in A, z-y\in B$. So we need  $x+a'=y+b'$ for some $a'\in A, b'\in B$, or $x-y=b'-a'$. But $x-y=(x-y)\cdot 1$, so $x-y=(x-y)(a+b)=
(x-y)*b-(x-y)(-a)$. Take $z=x+(x-y)(-a)=x(1-a)+ya=xb+ya=xb+y-yb.$  Hence $z\in x+A, z\in y+B$.

You forgot to include one part of the theorem: that if $A$, $B$ are co-maximal, then $A\cap B=AB$. That is also easy. Clearly, $AB\subseteq A\cap B$. Suppose $a+b=1$, $a\in A, b\in B$ and $z\in A\cap B$. Then $z=z\cdot 1= za+zb\in BA+AB=AB$ since the ring is commutative.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the surjection part of the proof is clearer  in *vector language*, i.e. in the product ring, which has *pointwise* ring operations, e.g. $(a,b,c)(a',b',c) = (aa',bb',cc')$,

First, [by linearity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095229/242), to show $\phi$ is onto it suffices to show that its image includes the "basis" vectors $\,(1,0,0,\ldots),\ (0,1,0,\ldots),\,\ldots,\,$ since then e.g. $\,(a,b,c) = a(1,0,0)+b(0,1,0)+c(0,0,1)$.

$\ \ \ \ \begin{align}
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\text{We  get $\, (1,\color{#90f}0,\color{#0a0}0,\ldots,\color{#c00}0)\,$ as the ${\it product}$ of the following $\,v_j\,$ ($*\,$ denotes any element)}\\
 v_2 &= \overbrace{(1^{\phantom{.}\!\!},\color{#90f}0,*,*,\ldots)},\ \  {\rm i.e.}\ \  v_2 \equiv 1\!\!\pmod{\!A_1},\,\ v_2\equiv 0\!\!\pmod{\!A_2};\,\ \color{#0af}{\text{all $v_j$ exist}}\ \rm by\ below\\  
v_3 &= (1,*,\color{#0a0}0,*,\ldots),\ \  {\rm i.e.}\ \  v_3 \equiv 1\!\!\pmod{\!A_1},\,\ v_3\equiv 0\!\!\pmod{\!A_3}\\   
v_4 &= (1,*,*,0,\ldots),\ \ \cdots\\[-.4em]  
&\ \ \vdots\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\,\ {\rm i.e.}\ \  v_j\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{\!A_1},\,\ v_j\equiv 0\!\!\pmod{\!A_j}\\[-.4em] 
 v_k &= (1,*,*,\ldots,\color{#c00}0)
\end{align}$

$\color{#0af}{\text{All $v_j$ exist}}$ since by hypothesis $\,A_1+A_j = (1)\,$ so $\, a_1 + v_j = 1\,$ for some $\,a_1\in A_1,\, v_j\in A_j\,$ thus $\, v_j = 1-a_1\equiv 1\pmod{\!A_1}\,$ by $\,a_1\in A_1,\,$ and $\,v_j\equiv 0\pmod{\!A_j}\,$ by $\,v_j\in A_j,\,$ as sought.

We get all the other basis vectors $\,(0,1,0,\ldots),\, (0,0,1,\ldots),\,\ldots\,$ in exactly the same way.

**Remark** $\, $ In a PID the hypothesis $\,A_i + A_j = (1),\, i\neq j\,$ becomes $\,(a_i)+(a_j) = (1),\,$ i.e. the moduli $a_i$ are pair-coprime $\,(a_i,a_j) = 1,\,$ a special case of the [classical CRT solvability condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1857626/242), which generalizes widely as explained there (it's one of many characterizations of Prufer domains - non-Noetherian generalizations of PIDs and Dedekind domains).

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3509367/242).