# Verification of quotient ring by Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

If F is a field then is $F[x]/\left<x^2\right> = F \times F$  correct by *CRT* ? Can we write $F[x]/\left<x^2-1\right> = F \times F$ by *CRT* ?   I think both can be written in the corresponding forms. If any mistake, please verify it.

Comment: Special cases of [this Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3509367/242)

Answer (score 0):

The first guess you gave will always be wrong. The quotient by $x^2$ has nonzero nilpotents but $F\times F$ does not.  It cannot be “correct by the CRT” because the CRT doesn’t apply.  I think you need to go back and read it again.

If $F$ has characteristic $2$ the second guess also fails for the same reason.

For fields not of characteristic $2$ though the Chinese remainder theorem will take hold because $R=(2)=(x+1, x-1)$, the factors are coprime.

Comment: Following your hint, could I say that in the first case , F[x]/<x²> has two elements (namely x +<x²> and 0+<x²> )that satisfies equation of the form t²=0 , whereas in F² there are only one element, which is 0 , satisfies the equation t²=0 . So F[x]/<x²>and F² are not isomorphic as field ?

Comment: @PritamRoy That is correct.